# Static code analysis WITH dynamic code analysis tools?

Tags: code-analysis, fxcop

Why have I never seen an analysis tool that has both static code analysis AND dynamic code analysis, therefore checking them both?

A side note, FxCop uses CIL parsing and call graph analysis to run its checks. Does anyone know if it uses dynamic or static call graph analysis?

I admit, I have limited knowledge of these tools, but have been doing some research and can't seem to find the two together... if you do know of some tools that do both, please list them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does make sense to combine both: you clearly want static analysis to detect *real* problems (not just *plausible* problems) and report them.  For those places where the static analyzer is sure there is NOT a problem, nothing needs to be done or said.  For those places where the static analyzer can't figure it out... you want dynamic analysis to watch for bad events at runtime.

The basic answer is that tools that do static analysis are generally not well provisioned to instrument application codes, and those that instrument don't have  lot of support for static analysis.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is a set of infrastructure that has both capabilites and can be used to build such tools.  At its core, DMS is a program analysis and transformation system. The analysis side parses code and builds models (ASTs, symbol tables, control/data flow graphs, etc.) on which to base analyzers.  The transformation side can modify the ASTs (using the analyzers to determine what to change) and spit out modified source code with arbitrary changes; for the purpose of this discussion, instrumented code.

A clear overview of how DMS can be used to instrument code (dynamic analysis) is provided in this paper: [Branch Coverage for Arbitrary Languages Made Easy](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf).

A more sophisticated example that combines both static and dynamic analyis is our [CheckPointer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety) tool, which detects pointer errors where made (as opposed to downstream damage).  CheckPointer combines (at this early time of its life) primarly dynamic analysis to achieve this effect coupled with some (and planned further) static analysis to eliminate as many of the dynamic checks as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not aware of a one tool that does both static and dynamic analysis, tool vendors have partnered together to offer this capability.  A good example of this is the Polyspace static analysis tools from MathWorks and the VectorCAST dynamic analysis tool from Vector Software.

Example use of these tools together:

1. Using static analysis to help get better code coverage. E.g. the static analysis tool can identify dead or unreachable code which will be impossible to get test coverage.
2. Using range analysis from the static analysis tool to develop test-cases that can then be used in the dynamic analysis tool.
3. Use code rule checking features in the static analysis tool (e.g. MISRA or JSF++) to develop better code that results in software that has better coverage analysis.

For further reading, here is a link to an article describing how these tools can be used together: http://www.vectorcast.com/blog/2011/04/25/combining-dynamic-testing-static-verification-part-1/